# c++ Passing List Of Classes In Function Parameter

Tags: c++, list

I have been trying to pass a instance of a class "person" to a function to print the contains of that list,but am unsure how to solve the errors.

```
Program::Program()
{

list<Person*> people;
list<Person*>::iterator iter;

cout << "Hello, Please Enter The Number Of People " << endl;
cin >> Maxpeople;
{
    for (int i = 0; i < Maxpeople; i++)
    {
        Person *p1 = new Person();

        cin.ignore();
        cout << "Hello " << endl;
        cout << "Please Enter The Name Of Person " << i + 1 << endl;
        getline(cin, input);
        p1->setname(input);

        people.push_back(p1);
    }
    Program P;

    P.print(people, iter); <----Call Print Function

    getline(cin, input);
}

 //header
 void print(list<Person*> p, list<Person*>::iterator i);
 //header

void Program::print(list<Person*> p, list<Person*>::iterator i)
{
    for (i = p.begin(); i != p.end(); i++)
    {
        cout << (*i)->getname() << endl;
    }
}
```

Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error   C2061   syntax error: identifier 'list' App1    c:\users\alasdair\documents\visual studio 2015\projects\drawstudio\c++fun\app1\stdafx.h 26
Error   C2061   syntax error: identifier 'list' App1    c:\users\alasdair\documents\visual studio 2015\projects\drawstudio\c++fun\app1\stdafx.h 26
Error   C2511   'void Program::print(std::list>,std::_List_iterator>>)': overloaded member function not found in 'Program' App1    c:\users\alasdair\documents\visual studio 2015\projects\drawstudio\c++fun\app1\app1.cpp 55
Error   C2061   syntax error: identifier 'list' App1    c:\users\alasdair\documents\visual studio 2015\projects\drawstudio\c++fun\app1\stdafx.h 26

I believe looking at the errors c2061/2511 I am not defining the type of lists correctly.Any help will be greatly appreciated,thanks.

---update one -----

Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error   C2065   'Person': undeclared identifier App1    c:\users\alasdair\documents\visual studio 2015\projects\drawstudio\c++fun\app1\stdafx.h 26
Error   C2059   syntax error: '>'   App1    c:\users\alasdair\documents\visual studio 2015\projects\drawstudio\c++fun\app1\stdafx.h 26
Error   C2955   'std::list': use of class template requires template argument list  App1    c:\users\alasdair\documents\visual studio 2015\projects\drawstudio\c++fun\app1\stdafx.h 26
Error   C2976   'std::list': too few template arguments App1    c:\users\alasdair\documents\visual studio 2015\projects\drawstudio\c++fun\app1\stdafx.h 26
Warning C4717   'Program::Program': recursive on all control paths, function will cause runtime stack overflow  App1    c:\users\alasdair\documents\visual studio 2015\projects\drawstudio\c++fun\app1\app1.cpp 53

Comment: You never added anything to any of your lists, and leaked `Maxpeople` `People` allocations. And if it worked, you'd be making copies of your `list` every time you printed. For the record, providing the string info on the errors and the lines they appear for would be helpful; it's annoying to have to look up the codes and guess at which line caused it.

Comment: It's not `list`, it's `std::list`. And don't forget to `#include <list>` - it seems you have included it in the .cc file where `Program` is implemented, but not the header where it's declared.

Comment: I tried that and am still getting errors although I had included <map> in the header, see update 1 in the first reply.

Comment: Can you update your question with all inclusions? Also, let's do it step by step. Can you comment out as much lines as possible so that there is still an error present? That's the idea of a [http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve](Minimal, Complete and Verifiable Example).

Comment: That said, ShadowRanger is right, you make a copy every time you print it. This might work right now but will cause you a lot of unnecessary run time when the list gets big. Simply fix this by making the list a reference: "void Program::print(list<Person*>& p, ..." <<< see the &-symbol that I inserted? That's a so called "call by reference", you might want to look that up on a search engine.

Comment: Rereading it, there is a lot of stuff that can be improved. Some parts remind me more of C. I'd strongly recommend you to get some sort of teacher, if not in person then maybe in a forum. There is no reason to declare people and iter as global variables and there is no reason to use iter as an argument - it would suffice to declare it in the setup of the for-loop within print, "for(list<Person*>::iterator iter = p.begin(); ...". Since print does not change the list, you should use the const keyword. people contains pointers which are never deleted, possibly creating a memory leak.

Comment: Many thanks for you reply,I think It will be best if I do a little more reading up. thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I figured out what I was doing wrong(although I am using a list of strings and not a custom class)as the people who replied said I was not passing by reference correctly.For any one interested this is my code.Obviously you can use the `pop_front()` to retrieve the next value.
Many thanks for your help.

====Main====

```
#include "stdafx.h"

int main()
{
    std::string input = "";

    std::list<std::string> people;
    people.push_back("Harry");
    printlist(&people);

    std::cin >> input;
}

void printlist(std::list<std::string> *mylist)
{
    std::list<std::string>::iterator myiterator;

    for (myiterator = mylist->begin(); myiterator != mylist->end();myiterator++)
    {
        std::cout << mylist->front() << std::endl;
    }
}
```

====Header====

```
#pragma once

#include "targetver.h"

#include <stdio.h>
#include <tchar.h>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <list>

void printlist(std::list<std::string> *mylist);
```